# Invalid object name when starting the sql dependency

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my code

```
SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString(), getQuery());
```

where `getQuery()` is:

```
private string getQuery() {
            return "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM dbo.Customer";
        }
```

I got this exception:

```
Invalid object name 'SELECT firstName, lastName FROM dbo.Customer'.
```

#### Update

```
    private string getQuery() {
        return "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM dbo.Customer";
    }

    public void Initialization()
    {
        // Create a dependency connection.
        SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString(), getQuery());
    }


    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

        // Create a new SqlCommand object.
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            getQuery(),
            new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())))
        {
            // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            // Maintain the refence in a class member.
            // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
            dependency.OnChange += new
               OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
            // Execute the command.
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Process the DataReader.
            }
        }
    }
```

and then from outside, I do this:

```
printing p = new printing();
            p.Initialization();
            p.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Show us the code that actually queries the database. The code you've provided is irrelevant.. the place that executes the query is important.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead that is my query. i have no other queries

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I will update with more code

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I updated the question with my code

Comment: Sasa, I didn't realise this was for change tracking. My apologies - CodeCaster has provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [`SqlDependency.Start(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224871(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, where the second string indicates a queue name. `'SELECT firstName, lastName FROM dbo.Customer'` is not a valid queue name.

You need to create a SqlCommand for the query and [inject that in the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf4282bx(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dependencyCommand = new SqlCommand();
dependencyCommand.CommandText = getQuery();

sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(dependencyCommand);
sqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionString());
```

---

As for your edit, you already do that. Just remove the second argument to `SqlDependency.Start()`.

Comment: +1. I didn't even recognise the class the OP was using.

Comment: I updated my code and I am already using a command on the method `SomeMethod` could you check please and check if you answer will stil the same after my update?

Comment: No need to spam me, read the answer (especially the last sentence) and you'll be able to figure it out. If not, some more input than "please help" is required.

Comment: the `start` function cant be called by instance

Comment: Remove the second argument to `SqlDependency.Start()`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i would like to know if making the new instance of sql dependency inside the somemethod is good or not. or it is better to make it in the constructor? i mean, is making it inside the `somemethod` will make me notify when a change happens on db?

Comment: @Sasa I haven't worked with SqlDependency for a while. Can't say, sorry. It should work like this, if not, try the other approach.